# How to pack multiple files to deb at once?

Tags: debian, deb

I have a multiple files that I want to pack to deb, I usual use `dpkg-deb -b (folder-name)` for every file I want to pack.

Comment: Can you add an example of the multiple file?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have the required files : `control` , `conffiles` and `pckg_name` and `pckg_name.conf` under `/home/user_name/`

```
packg_name/package_name_1/DEBIAN/control
packg_name/package_name_1/DEBIAN/conffiles
packg_name/usr/bin/packg_name
packg_name/etc/packg_name.conf
```

`packg_name_1` = the version 1 of `packg_name`

The control file will contain some information like:

```
Package: packg_name
Version: 1
Maintainer: Mox
Depends: e,g : dkms
Priority: optional
Architecture: all
Description: Put the description here
```

change the ownership of all files to root:

```
chown -R root:root packg_name/package_name_1
```

Then, build the package using `dpkg-deb`:

```
dpkg-deb --build packg_name/package_name_1
```

[What is a Debian control file?](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics.en.html)

[What is a Debian conffile?](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics.en.html)